# What is an example of a function $f : X \to Y$ such that for some sets $A, B \subseteq X, f (A \setminus B) \neq f(A) \setminus f(B)$

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

From my understanding, I thought it would be any function that is non-injective but I'm not certain.

If it is a non injective function, something like $f(x) = x^2$ or $f(x) = |x|$ would suffice. Is this correct or am I completely off?

Comment: Please use MathJax; [here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: If the function is not injective, find a value that comes from multiple points, and let $B$ be all those points *except one of them*.

Comment: Consider the unique map $f : \{0, 1\} \to \{0\}$. Let $A = \{0\}$, $B = \{1\}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. From [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): **Your question should be clear without the title.** After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Answer (score 1):

$$X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$$
$$ f(1)=1,f(2)=2, f(3)=3, f(4)=f(5)=1$$
$$ A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$$
$$ B=\{1,2,3\}$$
$$f(A-B)=f(\{4,5\})=\{1\}$$
$$f(A)-f(B)=\emptyset $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be any function that's constant on $X$ and let $A, B \subseteq X$ be arbitrary subject to the condition that $A \not \subseteq B$.  Your examples also can work for the right choices of $A, B$.